# OpenGL ES2.0 Load 8-bit image into Stencil Buffer

Tags: opengl-es

I am learning OpenGL ES2.0. I need a stencil buffer in my project.

```
What I am going to do:
1) Create a stencil buffer.
2) Load a 8-bit gray color image into this stencil buffer (which is also 8-bit per pixel).
3) The gray color image has different area (by setting different part a different value),       so I can render for each area by changing the stencil test value.
```

I've searched for a lot time, still have no idea on how to load the image into stencil buffer.

[image]
[image: Image 2]

So for the image above, I set stencil value as 1 for the blue area, and set 2 for the greeen area. How to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bitmap were 1 bit, just write a shader that either `discard`s or allows pixels to proceed based on an alpha test, or use `glAlphaFunc` to do the same thing if under the fixed pipeline, and draw a suitable quad with the appropriate `glStencilFunc`.

If it's 8-bit and you genuinely want all 8 transferring to the stencil, the best cross-platform solutions I can think of either involve 8 draws — start from 0, use `glStencilMask` to isolate individual bits, set `glStencilOp` to invert, test for non-zero in the relevant bit in your shader — or just using the regular texture and implementing the equivalent of a stencil test directly in your shader.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can u plz explain more about this: "or just using the regular texture and implementing the equivalent of a stencil test directly in your shader"? I am going to use 8-bit stencil,

Comment: You'd sample the texture in your shader and decide whether to `discard` (or in ES possibly output with alpha 0 if your blend mode makes that look like a discard, since that gives better performance on PowerVR) based on its value. You'd be implementing the stencil test yourself rather than using the fixed one. Would cost you a sampler. If the pattern you want to put into the stencil is supposed to stay there indefinitely then it'd be smarter to go to the effort of bit-by-bit insertion. Could you comment on why you want an 8-bit stencil? What do you intend to achieve that you couldn't in 1 bit?

Comment: Hi, What I am going to do is photo collage. plz refer my sencond picture, I may have serveral areas on screen, that's why I need 8-bit stencil instead of 1. This is picture is just a demo, in reality, it's a 8-bit gray image with 0, 1, 2, 4 value for each area. So What I want to do is load this 8-bit image into stencil buffer! Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so there aren't actually really soft edges to your stencil? You're not expecting it to do something like multiply into the alpha channel?

Comment: Hi I find what I understand about Stencil is wrong, I read this: https://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/source/browse/trunk/Android/Ch11_Stencil_Test/src/com/openglesbook/stenciltest/StencilTestRenderer.java  . So what I am going to do is create a bitmap on the air, the bitmap contains several regions(the regions with value 1, 2, 3 ...). then I draw for each region(discard those out side current region), by this I can set the proper stencil value for the stencil buffer. Any comment on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will do this experiment later, obviously, it's not efficient, but I will try first!